# Issue Deploying a Grails 2.1.1 app to JBoss because of Xerces

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, xerces

I have a Grails app that uses the Rest plugin

When I drop my war into my JBoss deploy directory and start it up, the deployment of the app fails because of the following error:

```
2012-11-01 15:48:33,931 ERROR [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.JBossContextConfig] XML error parsing: context.xml
org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Failed to create a new SAX parser
```

I believe this refers to the grails app containing a version on xercesImpl as well as JBoss having it's own. We usually rectify this by removing xercesImpl from our apps or setting them to "provided" scope.

I'm trying to figure out how I fix this deploy issue. I'm assuming I have to edit the BuildConfig.groovy script and tell it, somehow, to exclude xerces right? How would I do that for this plugin? If this were a "dependency" that appears to be easy to specify the exclusions. But I'm not sure how to do it for this plugin...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, doing the following in the plugin section of my BuildConfig.groovy did the trick after all...

```
compile(":rest:0.7"){
   excludes "xercesImpl"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `BuildConfig.groovy` add this:

```
inherits('global') {
   excludes 'serializer'
}
```

Comment: Bingo! That did the trick. If you don't mind me asking, is this documented somewhere in the grails docs that I missed?

Comment: I'm not sure, but running into this problem is definitely a rite of passage for Grails developers.

Comment: run `grails dependency-report`, you may be picking it up from one of your plugin dependencies.  Likely culprits are `xml-apis and xercesImpl`. If you see them add an exclusion.

Comment: That was my problem I saw initially was that the REST plugin I'm using is pulling in xercesImpl so I was asking how to exclude xercesImpl from the plugin I'm using... The REST plugin is not currently listed in the plugins section of my BuildConfig.groovy and I don't have any dependencies listed here. So how/where do I write the exclusion?

Comment: Looks like it might not even work at the moment excluding a transitive dependency from the plugin I'm using

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9188

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18993/discussion-between-kevin-m-and-proflux)